# Recursively parsing a json file using Jackson Json parser

Tags: json, jackson

I'm trying to recursively parse a sample Json file that has many sets of complex elements.
And the code that i'm trying is this :

```
public class Jsonex {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            Jsonex jsonExample = new Jsonex();
           jsonExample.testJackson();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
        }       
    }
    public static void testJackson() throws IOException {       
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
       // System.out.println("hello");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        File from = new File("D://albumList.txt");
        TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {};
        HashMap<String,Object> o= mapper.readValue(from, typeRef);
       // System.out.println("" + o);
        Iterator it = o.entrySet().iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()) {

          Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());

           HashMap<String,Object> o1=mapper.readValue(pairs.getValue().toString(),typeRef);
          System.out.println("hey"+o1);
           Iterator it1 = o1.entrySet().iterator();
           while (it1.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pairs1 = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                System.out.println(pairs1.getKey() + " = " + pairs1.getValue());
            it1.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificat



    }   
    }
}}
```

and i get this exception :

Exception org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@2de7753a; line: 1, column: 3]

**Actually what im trying to do is, parse the file and get list of name object pairs, and take the object which inturn has name-object pairs. - but the problem is that the parser is expecting "" before strings !**

Comment: Could you show some JSON? Why is it not valid? At least for field names you can configure [JsonParser.Feature ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.Feature.html#ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES) on the ObjectMapper.

Comment: {"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}

Thanks so much, that worked but there is a new exception.It says
Exception org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@2de7753a; line: 1, column: 5]
now. please help me @nutlike

Comment: When I asked for JSON I meant **your** JSON and not from http://json.org/example.html ... please update your question accordingly. Beyond that (once again): Why is your JSON not valid? Where do you get it from?

Comment: that is the json file that i actually parsed.. my program took this one as the input!

Comment: Ok, I was confused because all fields were proper quoted - I have missed the second `mapper.readValue(…)` in your code. I added an answer which may help you to rethink/redesign your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of parsing everything by yourself you should consider to use Jacksons built-in tree model feature (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
File from = new File("D://albumList.txt");
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(from);  

Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fields = rootNode.fields();
while (fields.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field = fields.next();
    System.out.println(field.getKey() + " = " + field.getValue());
    …

}
```

This should be more convenient in the long run. Have a look at the API at http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html.

Comment: sorry, i still dint find out a way as to how to iterate once i have the root node. I am totally new to json. The basic problem that i have is i dont know the element names apriori @nutlike

Comment: @sreeraag: I updated my example. I think you should be able to figure out the missing parts if you study the API linked in my answer.

Comment: it still does the job only at one level of hierarchy, doesnt work for multiple levels, for eg in above example, popup is totally given as one entity but is a complex element itself

Comment: Use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) in conjunction with isArray(), isObject(), fields() and elements(). This is a basic programming task …

Comment: Although its pretty old answer but even then I want to correct the call of rootNode.fields(); to rootNode.getFields();

Answer (score 4):

Just a comment. As you know there are 3 major processing modes that Jackson supports (Data Binding, Streaming API and Tree Model). You need to take into account that if you decide to use the Tree Model, acording to the official docs, the memory usage is proportional to content mapped (similar to data binding), so tree models can NOT be used with huge Json content, unless mapping is done chunk at a time. This is the same problem that data binding encounters; and sometimes the solution is to use Stream-of-Events instead.